# How to Increase Vector length to 200 after new Vector.<String>(100);

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

HI All,

//Created Vector with the initial length of 100.

var v:Vector. = new Vector.(100);

v[90] = "Ninety"

v[190] ="oneninety"  //RangeError: Error #1125: The index 110 is out of range 100.

//How to change the length from 100 to 200 to store a value at index 190
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the size of a Vector you just set the `length` property. eg:

```
v.length = 200;
v[190] = "something"; // works now
```

Comment: in addition to Marplesoft's answer, make sure the Vector object's property "fixed" isn't set to true if you want to be able to change its length.  by default the fixed property is set to false.

Comment: Thanks TheDarkIn, I know that.